# How to take a list of identical view components

Tags: java, android, view

Is it possible to somehow take an array, for example, a TextView, which are in the current Activity, or is it necessary to take each view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can get all the views of your xml programmatically as below:**

- bind your ViewGroup / Parent layout
- Then the child View are accessible in if condition

  val container = findViewById(R.id.container) as ViewGroup

  ```
       for (i in 0 until container.childCount) {
           val v = container.getChildAt(i)
           if (v is Button) {
               // You will get Button here
           }
           else if(v is TextView){
               // You will get textView here
           }         
       }
  ```

Comment: Can you write this code in Java, please?))

Comment: `ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);

    for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = container.getChildAt(i);
      
        if (!(v instanceof Button)) {
           
        } else {
                   }
    }`